# Breaking ties with more than 1 columns without using package R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Suppose I have the following matrix:

```r
output <- cbind(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1),
                c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1), c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I want to break ties for the 4th column with the 3rd and then with 2nd and then the 1st, i.e.
I would like to end up obtaining this matrix instead.

```r
output_1 <- cbind(c(1,2,5,3,4), c(1,1,1,2,3), c(1,1,1,1,2), c(1,1,1,1,1))
```

I tried to do `output_1 <- output[order(output[,4],output[,3], output[,2], output[,1]),]` which gives me the output I want. But is there a way to automate it, so that every time I have a new column, I don't need to hardwire inserting it.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to order programmatically is to use `do.call` on a list of the ordering components (matrix columns).

```r
output[do.call(order, rev(asplit(output, 2))),]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    2    1    1    1
# [3,]    5    1    1    1
# [4,]    3    2    1    1
# [5,]    4    3    2    1
```

Walk-through:

- `asplit(., 2)` converts a matrix into a `list`, where `MARGIN=2` means by-column. We could easily have just list-ized a subset of columns
- since you want to prioritize them last-column-first, its easy-enough to `rev`erse them; it's also easy enough to use a specific order, as in `asplit(output,2)[c(4,2,3,1)]`;
- (Note that we could have `asplit` and ordered in a different order, such as `asplit(output[,4:1], 2)` and no  need for  `rev`.)
- that is  a `list`, which is precisely what `do.call` needs as its second argument; if you aren't familiar with  `do.call`, then the following are equivalent:

  ```r
  L <- list(1:3, 4, 5:99)
  do.call(somefunc, L)
  somefunc(L[[1]], L[[2]], L[[3]])
  ```
- since the `do.call(order, ..)` returns an  integer vector of the  desired order, we just pass  that as the `i=` argument to `[` for matrix row subset/order.

Comment: Hello @r2evans, I very very much appreciate you taking your time to respond me in such detail. Thank you!